# ID is duplicating in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Go easy on me - only been working with rails for a week!

/author/**98**/5/books/edit/98

^^^ I can't get rid of the unnecessary first Book ID (98)

My Routes >>>

```
resources :author do
  member do
    get '/books', to: 'author_books#index'
    post '/books', to: 'author_books#create'
    patch '/books', to: 'author_books#update'
    delete '/books', to: 'author_books#destroy'
    get '/books/new', to: 'author_books#new'
    get ':author_id/books/edit/:id', to: 'author_books#edit', as: 'edit_book'
  end
end
```

Link >>>

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_home_author_path(f, @author) %></td>
```

Thank you in advance for any help :->

Comment: what is `f` there?

Comment: Also try passing ids explicitly `edit_book_home_author_path(id: book_id, author_id: author_id)`

Comment: <% @books.each do |f| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are overly declarative and verbose. Lean on resourceful routing more:

```
resources :authors, shallow: true do
  resources :author_books, path: "books"
end
```

This will create route handlers like this:

```
/authors          # => AuthorsController#index
/authors/42/edit  # => AuthorsController#edit
/authors/42/books # => AuthorBooksController#index
/authors/books/7  # => AuthorBooksController#show
```

And you can use the helpers like this:

```
link_to "Edit Book", edit_author_book_path(@book)
link_to "Edit Author", edit_author_path(@author)
```

Check [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) for the nitty gritty on `resources`, and see [Routing From The Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in the Rails Guide for a great overview and introduction.

Comment: Just a quick one - after implementing, I can't see a "edit_author_book_path"  in my routes?  Only Index, Create & New?

Comment: They're not prefixed, but they should be there. Because Rails doesn't need to know the author ID to route to the book for an author, you only pass in the book ID and end up with `GET /authors/books/:id/edit` where `:id` is the book ID.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks :>